# TypeError: Dispatch Action is not a function in Redux Toolkit

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redux, redux-toolkit

I am learning the redux toolkit and unfortunately, I have faced an error like Type Error but I failed to make a solution.

> Create Counter Slice

```
const { createSlice } = require("@reduxjs/toolkit");

const initialState = {
  count: 0,
};
const counterSlice = createSlice({
  name: "counter",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    increment: (state, action) => state.count++,
    decrement: (state, action) => state.count--,
  },
});
module.exports = counterSlice.reducer;
module.exports.counterActions = counterSlice.reducer;
```

> Configure Redux Store

```
const { configureStore } = require("@reduxjs/toolkit");
const counterReducer = require("../features/counter/counterSlice");

// Configure Store
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    counter: counterReducer,
  },
});

module.exports = store;
```

> Dispatch the redux Store

```
const store = require("./src/rtk/store/store");
const counterActions = require("./src/rtk/features/counter/counterSlice");

console.log(store.getState());

// subscribe to state chnages
store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log(store.getState());
});

// dispatch Actions
store.dispatch(counterActions.increment());
store.dispatch(counterActions.decrement());
```

> Error What I have faced like `TypeError: counterActions.increment is not a function` as given below,

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...                                                     
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
{ counter: { count: 0 } }
/media/imdad/Programming/MERN/Redux/Redux-Toolkit/rtkBasicSetup/app.js:12
store.dispatch(counterActions.increment());
                              ^

TypeError: counterActions.increment is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/media/imdad/Programming/MERN/Redux/Redux-Toolkit/rtkBasicSetup/app.js:12:31)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v18.17.0
```

***Can anyone please help me to solve this issue? The error is also given in the attached file please check it.***
[image: Error and Code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you didn't actually export the `counterSlice` actions correctly.

```js
module.exports.counterActions = counterSlice.reducer;
```

should be

```js
module.exports.counterActions = counterSlice.actions;
```

I'm not very familiar with module exports, but I think the `counterActions` are also incorrectly imported.

```js
const counterActions = require("./src/rtk/features/counter/counterSlice");
```

*should* probably be

```
const { counterActions } = require("./src/rtk/features/counter/counterSlice");
```

`counterActions.increment` should now correctly be a reference to the `increment` action/reducer declared in the state slice.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the problems I found in your code:

- Refactor your code and use ES6 instead of CJS. Here is an example:
  Change

  ```js
  const store = require("./src/rtk/store/store");
  ```

  to

  ```js
  import store from "./src/rtk/store/store";
  ```
- The second issue is that counterActions are imported as default module while it should be imported like this

  ```js
  const { counterActions } = require("./src/rtk/features/counter/counterSlice");
  ```

  or

  ```js
  import { counterActions } from "./src/rtk/features/counter/counterSlice";
  ```